# java -cp Error: Could not find or load main class (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, picocli

I'm basically following the next tutorial: https://picocli.info/#_running_the_application

And I'm trying to run my Application with the next command:

```
java -cp "picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" src/main/java/TestPicoCli.java --algorithm SHA-1 hello.txt
```

I'm located in a directory where I have the 2 jars `picocli` and `bashTool`, but I'm getting the next error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.TestPr.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.TestPr.java
```

This is how y directory looks like:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I just changed the class name :/, that's why I'm using TestPicoCli, in fact in the command I'm using: java -cp "picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" src/main/java/TestPicoCli --algorithm SHA-1 hello.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try `java -cp "picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" TestPicoCli --algorithm SHA-1 hello.txt`

Comment: I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

The command `java` can execute a compiled (bytecode) Java file `.class`
You are trying to execute a source file `.java` and it is not correct.

First, you need to find the `TestPicoCli.class` file. It could be generated by your IDE and is possibly in `target/classes`

Then, if you are in the folder that contains the `TestPicoCli.class`, you have to run:

```
java -cp "<path_to_your_jar>/picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" TestPicoCli // Without .class
```

Or if you are in the folder that contains the `.jar`, you should run:

```
java -cp "picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;<path_to_class_file>" TestPicoCli
```

**Note:** If you are on Linux, replace `;` with `:`

Comment: I'm getting the same error message with this approach :/

Comment: Could you add the relative paths of the jar and class files from where you are executing the command and the command itself?

Comment: for the PiciCli = "/Users/myUser/Documents/picocli/picocli-4.6.3.jar and for the bash= :/Users/rodolfosilva/Documents/picocli/bashLiftTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT. I'm in an Ubuntu Machine

Comment: Is the `bashLiftTool` also a jar?
I think the easiest way to test it is to copy the `TestPicoCli.class` to `.../picocli/` and **from there** run: `java -cp "picocli-4.6.3.jar:bashTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" TestPicoCli --algorithm SHA-1 hello.txt`.
If this doesn't work, the problem is not with the command. I assume your `TestPicoCli` file has a `main` method